# EditText dynamically changing text size- alternating between two sizes?

Tags: android, android-edittext, text-size

I'm trying to limit an EditText to have 3 lines at most, and if the user keeps typing, the font will change size to fit everything on three lines.

However, once I get past 3 lines, it is alternating between the original font size and the calculated one after each keyboard input.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
 {
        private String inputText;

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i,int i1, int i2) 
        {};

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1,int i2) 
        {};

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable ed)
        {
            int lineCount = editText.getLineCount();

            if(lineCount>=3)
            editText.setTextSize((float) 45/lineCount);
        };
```

Where 45 is simply what I'm using right now as I code.

Comment: Can't help you there but: note that if the user rotate the screen after inputting more than 3 lines, then you will have a more-than-3-line text with the original font because the entire UI is rebuilt. Same applies to other occasions where your activity ui is redrawn. Thus, you should handle this also in onCreate.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'll get a workaround for this

Comment: Sorry...my fault. The default implementation of onRetainInstanceState e onRestoreInstanceState should take care of that for you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the ">=" sign.... ugh. I'm now using a ">" to tell when it goes past 3 and working on a workaround to decrease the size based on how many times it's gone >3. I'll post my fix when its done.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to limit to 1 line and max 3 lines. Also wrap text around when it crosses 1 line.

```
android:minLines="1"
android:maxLines="3"
android:ellipsize="none"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
android:text="sample text, a lot of text to encourage wrap text"
```